# Is it possible to delete your emails after hiting send?

Tags: web-services, email, networking

I am not sur if I'm putting my quesion in the right place but I'll give it a try...
Well, I was wondering if there is a possibility to delete or modify my emails after sending them (using current protocols : SMTP, POP3 or IMAP ...).
If not, is it possible to build a new protocol than can do the job?

Thank you.

Comment: a mail transfer agent can delete and modify the emails that pass through it, that's how some spam and antivirus filters work. You need to give more details about what you actually want to do.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Actually, I want to develop a mini protocol (like imap for exemple) that allow someone, who sent an email by mistake, to delete it before the recipient read it or to modify it.